# Calling a method in a C dll fails

Tags: c#, dllimport

I try to call a dll method written in C from C#.

This is the C method:

```
char *c_ata(char * const c, const size_t c_len, const unsigned char * const b, const size_t b_len);
```

And this is the way i try to call it.

```
[DllImport(EntryPoint = "c_ata", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern string cAta(byte[] c, long c_len, byte[] b, long b_len);
```

The problem is i don`t get any error, when i try to run or debug my NUnit test.

I`am not really familiar with the C syntax, so the question is? Is the syntax of my call correct (in theory)?

Comment: The size_t arguments need to be IntPtr.  The string return value needs to be IntPtr as well or the marshaller is going to try to destroy the string.  Which very rarely works, C code doesn't often use CoTaskMemAlloc() to allocate memory that can be safely released in another module.  This is liable to be an unpluggable memory leak.  Convert the IntPtr with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  Write a test program that calls the function millions of times, watch memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, long specifies a 64 bit integer.  Is size_t 64 bit in your C code?  If not, the PInvoke signature should be changed to use int instead of long.

If a PInvoke signature is declared to return a string, the marshaller creates a string from the returned pointer and then calls CoTaskMemFree on the pointer.  That's only appropriate if the pointer was originally allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc.  If the native side does its own cleanup of the memory, the PInvoke should instead be declared return an IntPtr, which you can then make a string out of with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi or equivalent.